# How to mathematically judge if there is a spanning tree in a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Given a graph $G=(V,E,A)$ where $V$ is the set of the vertices, and $E$ is the set of sides, and $A$ is the adjacency matrix of dimension $n\times n$. $G$ is undirected or directed. We define the elements of $A$: if the side from $v_i$ to $v_j$: $e_{ij}\in E$, then $A_{ji}=1$, otherwise $A_{ji}=0$.

Question is how to mathematically judge if there is a spanning tree (minimal spanning tree) in this graph $G$? "Mathematically" means using the matrices (Laplace matrix, etc), and using mathematical calculus.

Comment: Perhaps "algebraically" would be more fitting than "mathematically".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm (among others) *construct* a minimal spanning tree, given a weighted undirected graph. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27_algorithm is an algorithm for the directed case. These can be phrased in terms of adjacency matrices if you want. In the undirected case, the existence of a minimum spanning tree is equivalent to connectedness, which can be detected through the graph Laplacian. The same might be true in the directed case (I've studied that case considerably less).

Comment: If you only want to look at the adjacency matrix, then the (undirected) graph is connected if and only if all entries of $B=I+A+A^2+\ldots+A^{n-1}$ are strictly positive.  In the case of digraphs, the graph is strongly connected iff $B$ has only positive entries, and it is weakly connected if $B+B^\top$ has only positive entries.

Comment: I made a mistake: in the case of digraphs, the graph is weakly connected iff $I+C+C^2+\ldots+C^{n-1}$ has only positive entries, where $C=A+A^\top$.